# android 2.3.3 inserting row into sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

so im running an app on android 2.3.3 which is inserting a row to a sqlite db.

This is how I add the row:

```
public static void addAlert(String inId, String inDate, String inLat,
            String inLng, String inAddress, String inComment)
    {
        Log.d("general", "adding alert to local list:");

        inAddress = inAddress.replace("null", ""); // remove null

        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put(ID, inId);
        insertValues.put(DATE, inDate);
        insertValues.put(LAT, inLat);
        insertValues.put(LNG, inLng);
        insertValues.put(ADR, inAddress);
        insertValues.put(COMMENT, inComment);

        Log.d("general", "" + db.insert(ALERT_TABLE_NAME, null, insertValues));
    }
```

Why does this not add a row to the local sqlite db?

The `db.insert( ... );` always returns 12 and no errors are given.

Answer (score 0):

If you pay attention at the docs of [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method, you will see that it will return -1 if error occurs or the row id inserted, so if it returned 12, it was successful inserted with row id 12.

Comment: yes and that is why I don't understand why it's not getting inserted. Every time I run this, it returns row 12 only but it should return row 13 next time so row 12 is not being inserted.

Comment: Can you post your table ddl?